# handleSubmit and onChange handleSubmit resulting in setState error or cannot enter character

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new to React and seem to be having an error with handleSubmit and onChange. It was working correctly to handle three events (I'd eventually like to have it where you are asked one question, then a conditional statement takes you to the next question).

I'm running into three different errors when I try to solve this problem.  I have handleChange affecting the onChange of three different text inputs.  If I try this on my input

`onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'input1')}`

with handleChange being:

```
      handleChange(name, event) {
    const change = {};
    change[name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(change);
    // this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

I cannot enter anything in the text input as it appears to be frozen.  If I change the order to

`handleChange(event, name)` I get an error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

And if I try this way (below) it works but then when I input text in any of the inputs, it changes all of them simultaneously.  I'm not sure how to solve this.  What I'd like to do is be able to individually put input in multiple text inputs.

Also, conditionals in React.js are still a little difficult for me, I'm not sure how to write it where when the first input is answered and submitted, it goes to the next one.

Here is the code that is working (kinda) but simultaneously updates in all three inputs

```js
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import styled from 'styled-components';
    import Crawler from './crawler';
    
    const NextQuestion = styled.div`
      position: absolute;
      color: white;
      display: block;
      margin-top: 108px;
    `;
    
    class NameForm extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          value: 'enter proper name',
          value2: 'noun',
          value3: 'enter another proper name',
          newValue: '',
          submitted: false,
          input1: 0,
          input2: 0,
          input3: 0
        };
    
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      }
    
      handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
          value: event.target.value,
          value2: event.target.value2,
          value3: event.target.value3
        });
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    
      handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('submit worked!!!');
        let toggle = this.state.visable;
        this.setState({ visable: !toggle });
      }
    
      render() {
        const divStyle = {
          marginTop: '50px',
          color: 'white',
          top: '25px',
          position: 'absolute'
        };
        let question = null;
        const show = this.state.visable;
        if (show) {
          question = (
            <div>
              <Crawler
                properName1={this.state.value}
                noun1={this.state.value2}
                properName2={this.state.value3}
              />
            </div>
          );
        }
        return (
          <div>
            <div style={divStyle}>
              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                  Proper Name:
                  <input
                    name="input1"
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.value}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                </label>
                <label>
                  Noun:
                  <input
                    name="input2"
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.value2}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                </label>
                <label>
                  Another Proper Name:
                  <input
                    name="input3"
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.value3}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
              </form>
            </div>
            <NextQuestion>
              {question}
            </NextQuestion>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default NameForm;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Please help.

Comment: why do you update the values of all the input to state, when only one is updated at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, `function.prototype.bind` passes the binded parameters first, and then passes the other parameters. Just a point to keep in mind while receiving arguments and working on it. Here is the reference to [function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Secondly, i like the approach where you would like to maintain a single function `handleChange` to update the state of all inputs, but you have implemented it wrong. I have made separate `onChange` function calls for each input and binded all of them to the same function `handleChange`, passing an additional parameter with the help of `ES6 function binding`. And you need not explicitly bind `this` to your functions as `ES6 Fat Arrows` takes care of that. Have a look at [ES6 arrow bindings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Third, I updated the handleChange function to update only the values that are changed, avoiding the unnecessary state changes of other input values.

I have provided the corrected solution, Hope this should work fine for you.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Crawler from './crawler';

const NextQuestion = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 108px;
`;

class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value1: 'enter proper name',
      value2: 'noun',
      value3: 'enter another proper name',
      newValue: '',
      submitted: false,
      input1: 0,
      input2: 0,
      input3: 0
    };

    this.handleFirstChange = (event) =>   this.handleChange(event, 'value1');
    this.handleSecondChange = (event) => this.handleChange(event, 'value2');
    this.handleThirdChange = (event) => this.handleChange(event, 'value3');
    this.handleSubmit = (event) => this._handleSubmit(event);
  }

  handleChange(event, type) {
    let newState = {};
    newState[type] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(newState);
  }

  _handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('submit worked!!!');
    let toggle = this.state.visable;
    this.setState({ visable: !toggle });
  }

  render() {
    const divStyle = {
      marginTop: '50px',
      color: 'white',
      top: '25px',
      position: 'absolute'
    };
    let question = null;
    const show = this.state.visable;
    if (show) {
      question = (
        <div>
          <Crawler
            properName1={this.state.value1}
            noun1={this.state.value2}
            properName2={this.state.value3}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={divStyle}>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>
              Proper Name:
              <input
                name="input1"
                type="text"
                value={this.state.value1}
                onChange={this.handleFirstChange}
              />
            </label>
            <label>
              Noun:
              <input
                name="input2"
                type="text"
                value={this.state.value2}
                onChange={this.handleSecondChange}
              />
            </label>
            <label>
              Another Proper Name:
              <input
                name="input3"
                type="text"
                value={this.state.value3}
                onChange={this.handleThirdChange}
              />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
        </div>
        <NextQuestion>
          {question}
        </NextQuestion>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NameForm;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```